# how to make an element available in web page without making the page heavy

Tags: html

I have a scenario where I have to place nearly 5000-10000 data in the web page at a time or part by part say(1000 at a time) but if I have to follow the 2nd option the database hits will be very high, so is it possible to place the entire set of data in the web page without making the page heavy.

Placing the data in cache is also not a very feasible scenario.
Please help me

Comment: Can you use ajax to get the info you need from the server?

Comment: By Data I mean Image, numbers, string , links. 
The 2nd option which I have mentioned is using ajax only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot keep it in client side (browser) without making the page heavy. In this case the fields will only be hidden, but the page will still have the data

You can use ajax. As you said, It will have more user request on server per page. But the Load on the server must not be heavily impacted. Coz, Even in the earlier case, you need to pass all the data from server to the client. 
On the other hand, the impact on the server can be less if you use ajax. Because, the server is passing only the data needed by the user. Not the entire data each time.